# Binding a list in java - efficiently

Tags: java, properties, javabeans

I have an object `myObject` which contains a property called `myThing`. The object `myThing` has an `ArrayList` and a property `list` which is connected to it. I have some `JLabel myLabel` which is bound to the `list` property.

To make this work, when the `firePropertyChange` is done, I have to make a clone of the list so that I pass a `PropertyChangeEvent` I have an old list and a new list to pass. This is very inefficient. Is there some way I should be doing this without the clone, that still allows me to bind properties?

Lists have been the bane of my existence lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cloning the List is the way to go in your case. You know, cloning a list only clone its structure, not all the members it contains, so its not "that" inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, though I was giving a simplistic version. In my real code my "myThing" is actually quite complicated with many methods and members, some of which do not support cloning, so cloning the real myThing will unfortunately be expensive in running time and programming time.

Comment: Well, it's not the answer I wanted; I may have to work around the problem I guess, perhaps leaving out binding and using my own events and listener. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be take care of  list clone.
it is a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance, but the elements themselves are not copied.
so, if you change copied ArrayList's element's property will be reflect to original ArrayList's element.

if you want your programs used ArrayList split, you should be rewrite ArrayList's clone method, use deeply copy.